# SQL Server Profiler 2012 Always has "master" listed under DatabaseName

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-profiler

I'm trying to identify some slow and databases and queries on SQL Server 2008 R2. I have been able to filter by time and display the database name succefully. However the DatabaseName always says 'master' with DatabaseID populated with '1'.

I know these queries are not being executed against master and I have over 300 hosted databases so I can't find out from context clues which database is causing the issues. Why isn't the database name populating correctly and how do I get it to populate?

Comment: **Side note**: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 have reached end of life several years ago and are now **completely unsupported**. You really should be looking at upgrading to a supported version.

Comment: If you were on a recent version, query store would be an excellent tool.